# Is there a method for converting a winmids object to a mids object?

Tags: r-mice, propensity-score-matching, brms

Suppose I create 10 multiply-imputed datasets and use the (wonderful) MatchThem package in R to create weights for my exposure variable. The MatchThem package takes a `mids` object and converts it to an object of the class `winmids`.

My desired output is a `mids` object - but with weights. I hope to pass this `mids` object to BRMS as follows:

```
library(brms)
m0 <- brm_multiple(Y|weights(weights) ~ A, data = mids_data)
```

Open to suggestions.

EDIT:  Noah's solution below will unfortunately not work.

The package's first author, Farhad Pishgar, sent me the following elegant solution. It will create a `mids` object from a `winmids`object. Thank you Farhad!

```
library(mice)
library(MatchThem)

#"weighted.dataset" is our .wimids object

#Extracting the original dataset with missing value
maindataset <- complete(weighted.datasets, action = 0)

#Some spit-and-polish
maindataset <- data.frame(.imp = 0, .id = seq_len(nrow(maindataset)), maindataset)

#Extracting imputed-weighted datasets in the long format
alldataset  <- complete(weighted.datasets, action = "long")

#Binding them together
alldataset  <- rbind(maindataset, alldataset)

#Converting to .mids
newmids <- as.mids(alldataset)
```

Additionally, for BRMS, I worked out this solution which instead creates a list of dataframes. It will work in fewer steps.

```
library("mice")
library("dplyr")
library("MatchThem")
library("brms") # for bayesian estimation.  

# Note, I realise that my approach here is not fully Bayesian, but that is a good thing!  I need to ensure balance in the exposure.  

# impute missing data 
data("nhanes2")
imp <- mice(nhanes2, printFlag = FALSE, seed = 0, m = 10)


# MathThem.  This is just a fast method
w_imp <- weightthem(hyp ~  chl + age, data = imp,
                     approach = "within",
                     estimand = "ATE",
                     method = "ps")

# get individual data frames with weights
out <- complete(w_imp, action ="long", include = FALSE, mild = TRUE)

# assemble individual data frames into a list 
m <- 10
listdat<- list()
for (i in 1:m) {
  listdat[[i]] <- as.data.frame(out[[i]])
}

# pass the list to brms, and it runs as it should!

fit_1 <- brm_multiple(bmi|weights(weights) ~ age + hyp + chl,
                          data = listdat,
                          backend = "cmdstanr",
                          family = "gaussian",
                          set_prior('normal(0, 1)',
                                    class = 'b'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`brm_multiple()` can take in a list of data frames for its `data` argument. You can produce this from the `wimids` object using `complete()`. The output of `complete()` with `action = "all"` is a `mild` object, which is a list of data frames, but this is not recognized by `brm_multiple()` as such. So, you can just convert it to a list. This should look like the following:

```r
df_list <- complete(mids_data, "all")
class(df_list) <- "list"

m0 <- brm_multiple(Y|weights(weights) ~ A, data = df_list)
```

Using `complete()` automatically adds a `weights` column to the resulting imputed data frames.

Comment: Thanks Noah, I can work with this!   See comment below for ideal workflow.  Your packages are incredibly useful b.t.w!  Thanks for all you do. 

Comment: Noah, unfortunately, your proposed solution does not work. It will throw an error. The correct solution appears to have been deleted. I will attempt to state it again for those who want a solution for integrating MatchThem with BRMS.

Comment: I made some edits to my answer to isolate and solve the problem. I also made a [bug report](https://github.com/paul-buerkner/brms/issues/1383) to `brms` since I believe my original solution should not throw an error.